# Testing the twitter app on local server in django with twython

Tags: python, django, twitter, python-twitter, twython

I am using the [twython library](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython), to do handshakes with twitter python library.
And I am testing things on my local server, 127.0.0.1:8000

This is my first django view, that generates the twitter tokens for users.

```
def twitter_auth(request):
    """
        The view function that initiates the entire handshake.
        For the most part, this is 100% drag and drop.
    """
    # Instantiate Twython with the first leg of our trip.
    twitter = Twython(
            settings.TWITTER_KEY,
            settings.TWITTER_SECRET,
            )
        # Then send them over there, durh.
        tw_callback_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('social_home'))
    twitter_auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens(callback_url=tw_callback_url)
        request.session['twitter_auth'] = twitter_auth
    return HttpResponseRedirect(twitter_auth['auth_url'])
```

From the above view, the user is redirected to the second view, where I wish to read the timeline of the user, I do it in following manner -

```
def social_home(request):
    oauth_token_secret = request.session['twitter_auth']['oauth_token_secret']
    oauth_token = request.session['twitter_auth']['oauth_token']
    twitter = Twython(settings.TWITTER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_SECRET, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
    authorized_tokens = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(request.GET['oauth_verifier'])
    user_tweets = twitter.get_home_timeline()
    return render(request, "social_summary.html", {"user_tweets":user_tweets})
```

But here, I get the following error - 
**Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid or expired token**

Please help me know, where I am wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might need the `get_authentication_tokens` instead ?

Comment: done, same result. `Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Failed to validate oauth signature and token`

Comment: One more thing i would do is check the API key and Secret credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def social_home(request):
    oauth_token_secret = request.session['twitter_auth']['oauth_token_secret']
    oauth_token = request.session['twitter_auth']['oauth_token']
    twitter = Twython(settings.TWITTER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_SECRET, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
    authorized_tokens = twitter.get_authorized_tokens(request.GET['oauth_verifier'])

    twitter = Twython(settings.TWITTER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_SECRET, authorized_tokens['oauth_token'], authorized_tokens['oauth_token_secret'])
    user_tweets = twitter.get_home_timeline()
    return render(request, "social_summary.html", {"user_tweets":user_tweets})
```

That should work! :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks it started working, but any idea, why you had to add the extra `twitter = Twython(settings.TWITTER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_SECRET, authorized_tokens['oauth_token'], authorized_tokens['oauth_token_secret'])
`  Also, I do not want the user to authorize every time, in that I need to save the user specific, `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` in the database, or do I need to save the `authorized_tokens`??

Comment: You need to save the `authorized_tokens`

Comment: The `authorized_tokens` are the final tokens generated in the OAuth Flow